# Total one column of a file grouped by two other columns

Tags: bash, perl, awk, hash

I want to sum rows based on similar string before the first "-" sign. I have tried R, but the file is too big.

in

```
URS0000001D42-antisense_ATTTCGGTTGGGGAA 208
URS0000001D42-antisense_CATGCTCATAAGGAA 24
URS0000003804-lncRNA_GAGATCCTGGGTTTT    6
URS0000003CBA-antisense_CTGGGCTAGTGAACGCGGCGAAGT        14
URS0000003F61-antisense_AAAGTGCACTTGGACG        55
URS0000003F61-antisense_AAAGTGCACTTGGACGAA      4
```

out

```
URS0000001D42-antisense 232
URS0000003804-lncRNA 6
URS0000003CBA-antisense 14
URS0000003F61-antisense 59
```

Comment: To group things, use a hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$NF}END{for (i in a){print i,a[i]}}' FS='_| ' file
```

**Result**

```
URS0000003804-lncRNA 6
URS0000001D42-antisense 232
URS0000003CBA-antisense 14
URS0000003F61-antisense 59
```

Comment: Only got 0 in my output counts ??

Comment: I have ASCII text

Comment: >CAAAAACTGCGATTACTTTTGC 2<
>CTGCCCTGCGGATGCTGTCCTGGACCTGTTGGCACCACAGACA 4<

Comment: Do you have `tabs` as separators?? try: `FS='_| |\t'`

Answer (score 1):

Using a perl hash:

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

while (my ($key, $value) = <> =~ /^(.+)_.+\s+(\d+)/) {
  $hash{$key} += $value;
}

while(my($k, $v) = each %hash) { 
  print "$k\t$v\n";
}
```

Calling it:

```
$ script.pl < file
URS0000003CBA-antisense:  14
URS0000003F61-antisense:  59
URS0000003804-lncRNA:  6
URS0000001D42-antisense:  232
$
```

Probably can be done shorter, too. ;-)

And [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610445/reading-an-entire-file-into-a-hash-in-perl) another question for a very similar task with lots of answers.

Comment: How do you change the output to have tab between the name and the count?

Comment: Like this?: print "$k\t$v\n";

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl solution

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my %data;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ( $f1, $f2, $seq, $n ) = m/[^-_\s]+/g;
    $data{$f1}{$f2} += $fields[3];
}

for my $f1 ( keys %data ) {

    for my $f2 ( keys %{ $data{$f1} } ) {
        printf "%s-%s %d\n", $f1, $f2, $data{$f1}{$f2};
    }
}

__DATA__
URS0000001D42-antisense_ATTTCGGTTGGGGAA 208
URS0000001D42-antisense_CATGCTCATAAGGAA 24
URS0000003804-lncRNA_GAGATCCTGGGTTTT    6
URS0000003CBA-antisense_CTGGGCTAGTGAACGCGGCGAAGT        14
URS0000003F61-antisense_AAAGTGCACTTGGACG        55
URS0000003F61-antisense_AAAGTGCACTTGGACGAA      4
```

### output

```
URS0000003CBA-antisense 14
URS0000001D42-antisense 232
URS0000003804-lncRNA 6
URS0000003F61-antisense 59
```

The output is unordered because Perl hashes have no inherent order. It is a little more difficult to keep the output in the same order as the input data, as it is necessary to keep an array for each hash that keeps track of the order that the keys were created

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ( %data, @keys );

while ( <DATA> ) {

    my ( $f1, $f2, $seq, $n ) =/ [^-_\s]+/g;

    push @keys, $f1 unless $data{$f1};

    my $h2 = $data{$f1} //= {};

    push @{ $h2->{''} }, $f2 unless $h2->{$f2};

    $h2->{$f2} += $n;
}

for my $f1 ( @keys ) {

    for my $f2 ( @{ $data{$f1}{''} } ) {
        printf "%s-%s %d\n", $f1, $f2, $data{$f1}{$f2};
    }
}

__DATA__
URS0000001D42-antisense_ATTTCGGTTGGGGAA 208
URS0000001D42-antisense_CATGCTCATAAGGAA 24
URS0000003804-lncRNA_GAGATCCTGGGTTTT    6
URS0000003CBA-antisense_CTGGGCTAGTGAACGCGGCGAAGT        14
URS0000003F61-antisense_AAAGTGCACTTGGACG        55
URS0000003F61-antisense_AAAGTGCACTTGGACGAA      4
```

#### output

```
URS0000001D42-antisense 232
URS0000003804-lncRNA 6
URS0000003CBA-antisense 14
URS0000003F61-antisense 59
```